# How to add a sub folder to a domain?

Tags: dns, cpanel, web-hosting

I have a domain xyz.com hosted on a hosting platform. I used file manager of cPanel to add all my website content and the site works perfectly when I access www.xyz.com. Now, I want to host a different version of my website which should work with  the address www.xyz.com/version2, where "version2" is a new folder which I would be creating into which I would be ftp ing the files of the new version of the website. Please give some pointers on how can I can achieve this, so that I will have both xyz.com and xyz.com/version2 working as I explained.

Answer (score 1):

Just create new folder with **version2** name under public_html directory through file manager and upload your all content through FTP to your newly created directory. Update your site setting in configuration file and check your site.

Comment: "Update your site setting in configuration file and check your site."                        
Could you please tell me which file you are talking about and what would be the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by creating a subdomain. I referred the below article for help,
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-manage-domains/creating-a-subdomain